# Html.BeginForm FormMethod.Post submit button click not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Single page having three different registration form,based on single `ID` reference, I need to call the three different `[HttpPost]` `ActionResult` method ,when i click the submit button for first form it's goes to first action result method correctly.

```
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header class="section-header">
            <div class="tbl">
                <div class="tbl-row">
                    <div class="tbl-cell">
                        <h2>Company Registration Form</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <section class="tabs-section">
                <div class="tabs-section-nav tabs-section-nav-icons">
                    <div class="tbl">
                        <ul class="nav" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" href="#tabs-1-tab-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <i class="font-icon font-icon-cogwheel"></i>
                                        Company Registration Form
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#tabs-1-tab-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span>
                                        Company Social Network
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#tabs-1-tab-3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i>
                                        Company Reference
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!--.tabs-section-nav-->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active show" id="tabs-1-tab-1">
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <section>
                            <div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model =>Model.company.CompanyName, new { @class = "form-label semibold control-label" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.CompanyName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter the Company Name" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.CompanyName)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.ShortName, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.ShortName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter the Short Name" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.ShortName)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.Division, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.Division, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter the Division" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.Division)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.Email, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter your Email" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.Email)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Save" value="Save" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" onclick=" GetInfo();" />
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tabs-1-tab-2">
                        <br />
                        <section>
                            <div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanySocial.FaceBookID, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanySocial.FaceBookID, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter the Facebook Link" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanySocial.TwitterID, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanySocial.TwitterID, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter the Twitter Link" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanySocial.linkedinID, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanySocial.linkedinID, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter the Linkedin Link" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Previous" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-primary prev-step" />
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Save" value="Next" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" onclick="GetInfo1();" />
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tabs-1-tab-3">
                        Tab 3
                        <br /><br />
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Previous" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-primary prev-step" />
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Finish" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" />
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                </div><!--.tab-content-->
            </section><!--.tabs-section-->
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

ActionResult Code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddCompany(MainModel cmp)
        {

            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                }

                return View();
            }

            catch
            {
                return View();
            }

        }
```

When i click second Submit button it's again going to the same `ActionResult AddCompany(MainModel cmp)` but i need to go to `ActionResult AddSocial(MainModel Social)`

Here this code :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddSocial(MainModel Social)
        {
            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "paginationClickHandler", "paginationClickHandler();", true);
                }

                return View();
            }

            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Ajax Method:

```
function GetInfo() {
            var company = { companyName: document.getElementById('CompanyName').value, shortName: document.getElementById('ShortName').value, division: document.getElementById('Division').value, Email: document.getElementById('Email').value }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Company/AddCompany",
                data: '{cmp:' + JSON.stringify(company) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }

        function GetInfo1() {
            var Social = { faceBook: document.getElementById('FaceBook').value, twitter: document.getElementById('Twitter').value, linkedin: document.getElementById('linkedin').value }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Company/AddSocial",
                data: '{Social:' + JSON.stringify(Social) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A `submit` inside the form is going to post the form, even if you have an `onclick` action written. If you want it to instead call the javascript function, change the `<input>` to a `<button>` or `<a>` tag.

**EDIT**

Delete the form tag completely to prevent submission which is reloading your page.

Comment: If I use button tag means whether the data transfer to action result class or not ?? Individual form data will be transfer or not ??

Comment: The way you have it set up, it should pass all the data even without a form. The form is irrelevant because you are gathering all your fields in javascript before your ajax call.

Comment: Thanks ..and when I click the first button page refresh so next tab is not enable how to solve this .. please any idea

Comment: In general, an HTML form does a post or get just like an Ajax call from JavaScript. Use one or the other.

Comment: How to create active and disabled option in this registration form ..first submit click before two registration form disabled after submitting the value then active next tab ..any code plz help me

Answer (score 1):

Your button is still inside a form. So when you handle your button click in javascript, you need to make sure to prevent the default behavior of a submit button click inside a form ( the form submit).

Using unobtrusive javascript way, give a unique id to your button

```
 <input type="submit"  id="saveSocial" value="Next"  />
```

and now, bind click event on this button, prevent the default behavior using 
 jquery `preventDefault` method and call your js method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#saveSocial").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        GetInfo1();
    });
});
```

Also it does not make sense to return a full view from your action method when the call is from  ajax code. May be you should return a json response.

Comment: In my first button click page is refresh .. how to stop and enable second tap ?? Any idea ..

Comment: with the above code i posted in the answer, if you do not have any other script errors in the page, it will not refresh the page because you are doing an ajax post.

Comment: perhaps you should do the same thing for the first button and when the ajax call is successful, enable/show the second tab.

Comment: First button click the value is pass to action result .. after the page is refresh.. then second tab is not enable .. any idea

Comment: you do have a js function (`GetInfo`) trying to handle the click of the button and doing some ajax call. If your code does not have errors it should not do a page refresh (because it should not do a form submit, instead it should fo a ajax post). Looks like you have the same problem (you had for second button) there. Hence i suggested you to do the same solution i gave in the answer for first button as well.

Comment: How to create active and disabled option in this registration form ..first submit click before two registration form disabled after submitting the value then active next tab ..any code plz help me

Comment: None will write code for your entire feature. You should try yourself and if you are stuck at a specific problem, you should ask a question.

Comment: Sure sir @shyju

Comment: see the link already I ask this question another one account can u help me plz